# Prove that $g(t)=\frac{1}{t}(f(x+ty)-f(x))$ is monotone

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, monotone-functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function satisfying $f(x+y)\le f(x)+f(y)$ and $f(tx)=tf(x)$ for all $t\ge 0$, all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$.
Prove that the function $g(t):=\frac{1}{t}(f(x+ty)-f(x))$ is monotone for all $t\neq 0$.

I manage to show that $f$ is a convex function, but I struggle to proceed.
I considered the difference:
$$
\begin{align*}
g(a)-g(b) = \frac{1}{ab} (bf(x+ay)-af(x+by)-(b-a)f(x))
\end{align*}
$$
but due to the contraints $t\ge 0$, I couldn't make use of the convexity of $f$. Is there any promising way I can proceed?

Comment: 1/ Do you think it is monotone increasing or decreasing? 2/ Take $ m < n$, what is the equation that we want to show? How can we use the conditions in the problem to get us there?

Comment: @CalvinLin Assume $a<b$. We want to show that the difference $g(a)-g(b)$ is either $\ge0$ or $\le 0$, which I'm not sure about. What I did was shown in the question, but I coudn't proceed because of the constraint $t\ge 0$.

Comment: Right, so knowing if it's $ \geq 0 $ or $\leq 0 $ helps you decide what inequalities to try. EG We could use things like $ f(x + ay) \leq f(x + by) + (a-b) f(y) $ to simplify the RHS.

Comment: Can you think of an example? There is a fairly large class of simple examples...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\lambda>1,$ compute $$\begin{align} 
g(\lambda a)-g(a)=\frac{f(x+\lambda a y)-f(x)-\lambda f(x+ay)+\lambda f(x)}{\lambda a}\tag1\end{align}$$

So you need $$f(x+\lambda ay)-f(\lambda x+a\lambda y)+f((\lambda-1)x)\geq 0,$$ or possibly in the other direction. (But all basic examples of $f,$ norms of $\mathbb R^n,$ have $g(t)$ increasing and converging to $f(y),$ so we will check that first.)

$(1)$ is equivalent to:

$$f(\lambda x+a\lambda y)\leq f(x+\lambda ay)+f((\lambda-1)x).$$

But $$\lambda x+a\lambda y =(x+\lambda ay)+(\lambda-1)x.$$

This only solves for $b>a>0.$

We get it is increasing for $t<0$ by considering the same function for $(x_0,y_0)=(x,-y).$ Then $g_0(t)=-g(-t),$ and we know $g_0(t)$ is increasing for $t>0,$ so $g(t)$ is increasing for $t<0.$

---

Finally, we need $a<0<b.$ It seems we might want to show:

$$\lim_{t\to0^+} g(t)\geq \lim_{t\to 0^+} g(-t).$$

But this can be written as:

$$\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{f(x+ty)-f(x-ty)}{t}\geq 0.$$

But $$f(x+ty)\leq f(x-ty)+tf(2y).$$

So we need to know that $f(2y)\geq 0?$ Since $y$ is arbitrary, this would mean that $f$ has to be non-negative.

Not sure where to go from there.

---

Using $\lambda a>a$ rather than $b>a$ makes the common denominator simpler, making the formula $(1)$ cleaner. We can always get back to $b>a$ by taking $\lambda=\frac ba.$

Comment: But what if for example $a>0$ and $b<0$?

Comment: $g$ is defined for all $t\ne 0$. The constraint $t\ge0$ I was referring to was about the $f(tx)=tf(x)$. Sorry if that is confusing.

Comment: I assumed it was only defined on $t>0.$ But $g_0(t)=-g(-t)$ is comes from $x,-y,$ so it is also increasing for $t>0,$ and thus $g(t)=-g_0(-t)$ is increasing on $t<0.$ So we just need the case where $b<0<a.$ Would have to work on that.

Comment: I think we only need to show that $g(-a)\le g(a)$ for all $a\neq 0$, which is quite easy. Combining with your answer, I think the problem is solved.

Comment: I think we have to prove $f(y)\geq 0$ for all $y.$